# How to implement background image transition or smooth slider for navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can anyone suggest how to implement a navigation similar to this theme? http://themes.goodlayers.com/?theme=kingpower

When you hover on any menu item, the background image moves very smoothly left or right to the item on which we currently hover.

Please help if there are any plugins available to implement this or what is an alternative solution.

Comment: This is not a proper question and might even be intruding on IP or copyright from the theme's owner. Why you are receiving downvotes are probably due to the fact that you lack a real question and that the "question" you did ask is too broad, we're here to help, not do for you.

Comment: @Alex It is not intruding on copyright because the code that the question asks about is **open source**.

Answer (score -1):

This theme is using [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/), a jQuery menu plugin by [Joel Birch](https://github.com/joeldbirch).

It is open source / free software, dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:

- http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
- http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

See:

- http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/
- https://github.com/joeldbirch/superfish

for code to download and documentation on how to use it.